# BitLocker: how to allow non-admins to unlock the secondary drive?

Tags: bitlocker, non-admin

The primary and secondary harddrives on my computer are encrypted by BitLocker.

My account is a non-admin account. I can logon to my machine fine, but I cannot unlock my secondary drive - the only way for me is to get temporary admin rights on my machine to have the Harddrive unlocked.

Is any of the following possible?

. Allow my non-admin account to unlock the secondary Hard Drive.

. Automatically unlock my secondary drive when I logon to my computer - currently this option is greyed out on the BitLocker password screen.

Thanks.

Comment: This a domain computer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My tech wiz found the solution for the question 1 -i.e., **Allow my non-admin account to unlock the secondary Hard Drive.**

Here is what needs to be done:

1. In Windows Explorer, right click on the HDD and select the first
   option "BitLocker Encryption Options"
2. When you get the window "Microsoft BitLocker Administration and
   Monitoring", click on the "Unlock Drive"
3. Provide you password
4. Click on the "Unlock drive" option.

**Please note:** my boot password and secondary drive password are identical, I however do not think that they have to be identical.

Comment: "BitLocker Encryption Options" Does not even exist.